# Как заменить {{field}} {{ field.errors}} {{field.label}} на обычный HTML.?

Tags: django, jinja2

```
<form action = "{% url 'group_create' %}" method = "post" style="width:500px; margin-left:550px; margin-top:150px">
 {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {% if field.errors %}
            <div class = "alert alert-danger">
                {{field.errors}}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
       {{field.label}}
    {{field}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Легко. С чем именно у вас проблема?

Comment: У мене в той форме есть 7 полей, 2 из которых будут заполнятся после клика на гугл карту, соотвественно им(input-ам) нужно так-то дать id, пр которому JS наполним их значениями после клика на карту.

Comment: Они получат id и в приведённом вами коде.

Comment: А как им его происвоить в моём случае?

Comment: Или там id по дефолту есть?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#configuring-form-elements-html-id-attributes-and-label-tags